# Allow additional parameters to be passed to a URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Firstly, I apologies for my complete lack of understanding of MVC - I've been on WPF and Silverlight for four years and have just inherited an MVC app!

Using the system you can currently you can currently access a Vehicle using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:61276/Vehicle/12407
```

The number at the end is the Vehicles ID and runs through this piece of code in the Controller ...

```
public virtual ActionResult VehicleView(int id)
{
    var vehicle = VehicleService.Get(id);
    return View("VehicleView", new VehicleViewModel { VehicleDetail = vehicle != null ? vehicle.Details : null, Vehicle = vehicle, DetailDisplayType = "features"});
}
```

The last parameter is DetailDisplayType ...

I need to be able to change DetailDisplayType

I naively thought I could do it by adding another method like this ...

```
public virtual ActionResult VehicleView(int id, string detailDisplayType)
{
    var vehicle = VehicleService.Get(id);
    return View("VehicleView", new VehicleViewModel { VehicleDetail = vehicle != null ? vehicle.Details : null, Vehicle = vehicle, DetailDisplayType = detailDisplayType });
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> The current request for action 'VehicleView' on controller type 'SearchController' is ambiguous"

I need to keep the ability to reference the Vehicles with no DisplayType as they do currently, but have an optional display type ...

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the ambiguity by implementing only a single VehicleView action in your code. Your code should look like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult VehicleView(int id, string detailDisplayType)
{
    var vehicle = VehicleService.Get(id);
    return View("VehicleView", new VehicleViewModel { VehicleDetail = vehicle != null ? vehicle.Details : null, Vehicle = vehicle, DetailDisplayType = detailDisplayType??"features" });
}
```

The interesting stuff is the ??"features" at the second line in the action body. ASP.NET MVC feeds you a null into the detailDisplayType parameter in case this is not given somewhere in the URL (most likely that is a query parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Make the `detailDisplayType` parameter nullable and set it's route to `Optional`

```
routes.MapRoute("VehicleView", "vehicles/{id}/{detailDisplayType}",
    new {
        area = "",
        controller = "vehicles",
        action = "vehicleview",
        detailDisplayType = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

---

```
public virtual ActionResult VehicleView(int id, DetailDisplayType? detailDisplayType)
{
    var vehicle = VehicleService.Get(id);

    var model = new VehicleViewModel
    {
        VehicleDetail = vehicle == null ? null : vehicle.Details, 
        Vehicle = vehicle,
        DetailDisplayType = detailDisplayType ?? DetailDisplayType.Features
    }

    return View("VehicleView", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a single overload that takes both parameters, and make the second parameter optional with a default value of `"features"`.